# Two AutoCompleteTextField in same form

Tags: codenameone

I have 2 AutoCompleteTextFields in a form (database linked). The two of them are initialized with `.setText(value)` and then i show the form.

Then i noticed that the filter event is fired when i initialize them and when i show the form. I don't know if this the standard behaviour or if i am doing something wrong.

Can i somehow disable this first and second filter event call?

Besides that, it throws some Java null errors too. If i take out of the form the first or the second autocompletetextfield no error is shown.

Comment: If you get null pointer exceptions you need to provide the stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter is called initially to indicate that data has changed and initialize the data. You can create your own special case (e.g. first time) and do nothing there.

Comment: Thanks Shai. Tried that (If firsttime return false) and it was skipping the initial filter call. But some how then the dropdown list was only showing one element and wasnt positioned in the rigth place. It had a gap between the autocompletetextfield and the one element list. Tried this in the simulator and on the Phone.

Comment: If you can isolate that to a test case please file an issue